# Sending bytes over network on a device

Tags: java, c#, android, networking

I'm trying to write some string (as ascii) by using network stream (tcp/ssl) to server, i.e., local C# console app. The code looks like this:

```
public void SendMessage(String message) throws IOException {
   OutputStream stream = client.getOutputStream();
   // message is a String of 27 characters.
   stream.write(message.getBytes("US-ASCII"), 0, message.getBytes("US-ASCII").length);
   stream.flush();
}
```

This works fine on emulator, however, when I run app on my device (Galaxy A5 on Lolipop 5.0.2), it sends only one byte. What is the problem here ?

My receiving code on server side, I first try to read first four bytes (C#):

```
var messageData = new StringBuilder(); 
var buffer = new byte[4]; 
var bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4); 
var len = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer); 
var chars = new char[Encoding.ASCII.GetCharCount(buffer, 0, bytes)]; 
// Use Decoder class to convert from bytes to ACII 
// in case a character spans two buffers. 
Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(buffer, 0, bytes, chars, 0);
messageData.Append(chars);
```

Comment: Try using a `Writer`, but please use the same one for the life of the socket. Hard to believe it only sends one byte, unless the message is only one byte. Have you considered the possibility that the problem is at the receiving end?

Comment: No, because I'm debugging server app too. When run from emulator for the same message I receive 4 bytes, and when on device it receive one byte.

Comment: So? TCP is quite entitled to deliver one byte at a time. You have to loop. You'll have to post your receiving code.

Comment: My receiving code (C#):  var messageData = new StringBuilder();

            var buffer = new byte[4];

            var bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4);

            var len = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);

            var chars = new char[Encoding.ASCII.GetCharCount(buffer, 0, bytes)];

            // Use Decoder class to convert from bytes to ACII 
            // in case a character spans two buffers.
            Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(buffer, 0, bytes, chars, 0);

            messageData.Append(chars);

Comment: I'm receiving first four bytes always, which is lenght of the rest of the message.

Comment: Make up your mind. Either you receive one byte, or four bytes. You can't have it both ways. In any case the code you have posted doesn't *send* those four bytes. If you can't post code that demonstrates the problem, this question will be closed.

Comment: You don't understand what I'm saying. I receive first four bytes of a message, always. The server correctly receive it when app is in the emulator. However, when the app is on device, the server recives only one (first) byte. Is this clear enough ?

Comment: I understand what you have posted. It isn't complete. You are claiming the existence of a four-byte length word which you are never sending, and you have still not posted the receiving code: in other words you haven't yet demonstrated the existence of a genuine problem.

Comment: I didn't post receiving code ? Do you see my 4th message here ? My message string have 27 characters, in this case, but it's not important, as I receive only first character.

Comment: You can see for yourself that code in comments is illegible. I won't even attempt to read that. If you want it read, edit it into your question. You still haven't explained where the four bytes comes from, or why you think that TCP is obliged to deliver you more than one byte at a time. It isn't.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Have you considered trying to disable Nagle's algorithm when you create the TCP socket?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the standart StandardCharsets.US_ASCII instead of your hard coded String, which is always a bad idea.

yourString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);

Comment: Why I received -1 for this question, because I don't have answer ?

Comment: @Brght Why you received -1 for this question has nothing to do with this answer. You got the-1 from me, because your question doesn't yet make sense, despite several attempts on my part to get you to clarify it.

Comment: I don't agree with you. I explained my question precisely.

Comment: Yet you haven't got an answer yet. Strange, isn't it?

Comment: This means that I didn't properly asked or that no one knows answer ?

Comment: Until you satisfy the requirements of the people who are trying to help you you may never get an answer. You can argue about it as much as you like, but you don't get to make the rules.

Comment: O.K. Ban me. I gave you all of my code, and explained what's happening. I cannot do more than this.